# Rails user validation with one of two attributes, if present must be unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In defining a User with devise as the authentication mechanism, where one of two attributes can serve as an authetication key `devise :database_authenticatable, :authentication_keys => [:login_name]`, the fundamental requirement is

```
def at_least_one_identifier
  if [self.email, self.mobile].reject(&:blank?).size == 0
    errors[:base] << (I18n.t('user.define_email_or_mobile'))
  end
end
```

which in turn would necessitate a validation for the authentication key

```
validates :login_name, uniqueness: true
```

The login_name is one of two cases (*note, the form has a default `nation_id` value attributed*)

```
def login_name
  if self.email.nil?
    login_name = self.nation_id && self.mobile
  else
    login_name = self.email
  end
end
```

However, partial validations are required, i.e. the uniqueness of email and mobile when they are present.  Thus,

```
  validates :mobile, uniqueness: { scope: :nation_id, message: (I18n.t('user.define_one_mobile_per nation')) }  
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
```

won't cut it, as this will not allow more than one record with `nil` for each of these cases.

How can this be properly validated?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [Conditional Validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation).

```rb
validates :mobile, uniqueness: { scope: :nation_id, message: (I18n.t('user.define_one_mobile_per nation')) }, if: -> { mobile.present? }
validates :email, uniqueness: true, if: -> { email.present? }
```

This will result in the unique constraint only being checked if the specified parameter is not `nil`.